# Not able to Deserialize json string coming from kafka topic which has attributes in snake case

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, deserialization

Him

I am not able to deserialize a json string coming from kafka topic. 
Attributes are in mix of snake case and camel case structure, for example :
input :

```
{
"event_type" : "ABC",
"user_id" : 1567221,
"name" : "HGHAAAB" //here no snake case
"user_contact" : "12345678",
"phoneNumber" : "91222"
}
```

Now I want to create Request DTO on my side like below :

```
public class KafkaRequest { 
private String eventType;
private int userId;
private String name; 
private String userContact;
private String phoneNumber;

//getters and setters

}
```

Can any one suggest what should be the correct way? I tried creating CustomNameStrategy and deserializing with ObjectMapper.readValue() but it did not work.

Thanks is advance!!!

Comment: are you using `gson` or `jackson`?

Comment: Is this typo mistake  `private String userConatact` in your ocde?

Comment: @Deadpool : using gson, and what is the typo you're seeing?

Comment: @Deadpool : corrected the typo

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `jackson` you can either use `@JsonProperty` [6.1. @JsonProperty](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

```
@JsonProperty("event_type")
private String eventType;
```

Or you can set property [PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) to `ObjectMapper`

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Comment: There's a typo here: 

```private String userConatact```

Comment: probably that might be typo i believe @Migsarmiento let's ask OP

Comment: Hi @Deadpool , objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE) is working fine, but if I have another attribute phoneNumber in the request json, it's not working.

Comment: what do you mean it's not working for `phoneNumber` ? @PrafulJha

Comment: {
"event_type" : "ABC",
"user_id" : 1567221,
"name" : "HGHAAAB" //here no snake case
"user_contact" : "12345678",
"phoneNumber" : "91222"
} 
for this JSON - objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE) is not working

Comment: If all the properties are in not snake case then use @JsonProperty annotation on each field

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON there are way to define field name strategy

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().setFieldNamingStrategy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE_WITH_SPACES).create();
```

or even u can define custom as well

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String translateName(Field f) {
                return f.getName().toLowerCase(); //or any logic
            }
        }).create();
```

For Producer just StringSerializer will work

```
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
```

Assume you already have populated POJO say kafkaRequest then you can publish

```
ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("topicName", null, gson.toJson(kafkaRequest));
```

On Consumer side parse back to POJO

```
properties.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         KafkaRequest kafkaRequest = gson.fromJson(record.value(), KafkaRequest.class);
    }
}
```